# how to upload files to s3 with server side encryption enabled by custom kms key

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption

created 2 new kms key:

```
custom-client-side-encrypt-kms-key. (encrypt file on client side);
custom-server-side-encrypt-kms-key. (enable S3 server side encryption)
```

created new user:

```
test-user-encrypt
```

gave the user access to key and bucket;
set up new key policy to allow user to use the key

1. ran command(new user credential, with key id options)

```
 aws s3api put-object --body newFile --bucket <bucket-name> --key inbound/newFile --server-side-encryption aws:kms --ssekms-key-id newKeyId
```

error: when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

2. ran command (new user credential, without key id options)

```
aws s3api put-object --body newFile --bucket <bucket-name> --key inbound/newFile --server-side-encryption aws:kms
```

it works, but the object was encrypted with AWS managed default kms key

based on the above test, it seems the user has correct permissions to S3, but kms key permission was not correct.

here is my policies in brief:

key policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxid:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxid:user/test_user_encrypt"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:ReEncrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx",(IP addresses allowed)
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxid:user/test_user_encrypt"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:RevokeGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:CreateGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx", (IP addresses allowed)  
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM user policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:ReEncrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:<region>:xxID:key/custom-client-side-encrypt-kms-key-id",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
             "xx.xx.xx.xx" (IP address allowed)
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:RevokeGrant",
        "kms:ReEncrypt",
        "kms:ListGrants",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:CreateGrant"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:<region>:xxxID:key/<custom-server-side-encrypt-key-id>"
      "Condition": {
          "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
             "aws:SourceIp": [
                "xx.xx.xx.xx", (IP address allowed)
              
              ]
           }
        }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/inbound/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "xx.xxx.xxx.xx", (IP address allowed)
          
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/*/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/*/",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxid:user/test_user_encrypt"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/inbound/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx", (IP address allowed)
                    
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxid:user/test_user_encrypt"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/inbound/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx", (IP address allowed)
              
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptKey",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "arn:aws:kms:region:xxxid:key/custom-server-side-encrypt-kms-key-id"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you asking a question? If there is something you need help with, please update your question so that it is clear what you need help with.

Comment: @DanielMorell just updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I should NOT put condition "ip range" around kms:grant permissions.

```
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.xx.xx.xx", (IP address allowed)
              
                    ]
                }
            }
```

that condition make kms:grant invalid.  my guess....

after removed the condition, it works fine.